# Decode a Crockford base32-string with an ISO-7064 Mod 37, 36-checksum

Tags: php, base32

So I've been trying to wrap my head around this. I have a string encoded with Crockfords base32 algorithm, and a checksum based on ISO-7064 Mod 37, 36, which needs to be decoded in PHP.

String is "66QC" and checksum is "Q" which should be decoded to "203500. I've used [this class](https://github.com/dflydev/dflydev-base32-crockford/blob/master/src/Dflydev/Base32/Crockford/Crockford.php) to decode the string, but I'm still at a loss when it comes to the checksum. I can't seem to find any examples on this and feel lost. If someone has done anything similar or can point me the right direction it would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I found a working example in VisualBasic and translated it to PHP. So if anybody's interested:

```
class ISO7064Decoder
{
    public static $iso7064 = array(
    '0' => 0,
    '1' => 1,
    '2' => 2,
    '3' => 3,
    '4' => 4,
    '5' => 5,
    '6' => 6,
    '7' => 7,
    '8' => 8,
    '9' => 9,
    'A' => 10,
    'B' => 11,
    'C' => 12,
    'D' => 13,
    'E' => 14,
    'F' => 15,
    'G' => 16,
    'H' => 17,
    'I' => 18,
    'J' => 19,
    'K' => 20,
    'L' => 21,
    'M' => 22,
    'N' => 23,
    'O' => 24,
    'P' => 25,
    'Q' => 26,
    'R' => 27,
    'S' => 28,
    'T' => 29,
    'U' => 30,
    'V' => 31,
    'W' => 32,
    'X' => 33,
    'Y' => 34,
    'Z' => 35
);

public static function calculateCheckDigit(String $value)
{
    $lngCheck = 36;
    $lngLen = strlen($value);

    for($lng = 0; $lng <= strlen($value)-1; $lng++)
    {        
        $lngCheck = $lngCheck + self::charToNumber(substr($value, $lng, 1));

        if($lngCheck > 36)
        {
            $lngCheck = $lngCheck - 36;
        }
        $lngCheck = $lngCheck * 2;
        if($lngCheck >= 37)
        {
            $lngCheck = $lngCheck - 37;
        }
    }
    $lngCheck = 37 - $lngCheck;
    if($lngCheck == 36)
    {
        $lngCheck = 0;
    }

    return $lngCheck;
}

public static function charToNumber($value)
{
    $value = strtoupper($value);

    if(!array_key_exists($value, static::$iso7064))
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        return static::$iso7064[$value];
    }
}
}
```